# How to Flip the QGraphicsItem vertically using QPainter?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qpainter

I am trying to flip QGraphicsTextItem vertically with the following code but when I use Scale or transform function in QPainter to flip the GraphicsItem the text disappears.

```
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPainter>


class QTextItem : public QGraphicsRectItem {
public:
    QPointF point;
    QString text;
    QTextItem(qreal x, qreal y,QString txt, qreal width=50, qreal height=50, QGraphicsItem * parent = 0) :
        QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height, parent) {
        point = QPointF(x,y);
        text = txt;

    }


protected:
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*) {
        painter->setPen(QPen());
        painter->setFont(QFont("Arial", 5));
        painter->setBrush(brush());
        //painter->scale(1,-1);//Text disappears with this command
       //painter->rotate(30);//Text disappears if I use this command
        painter->drawText(point, text);
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried using painter->rotate(). If the angle is below 5 degrees, I am able to see the rotated text but I see that if the rotation is more it changes the position and goes out of the view.

Comment: If you want to rotate around the center, you have to use a transform chain of translate(center -> topLeft) -> rotate -> translate(back).